# JAVA: Searching for items in an arraylist only returns the first item

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

I have a Java program that ask for five string inputs from the user. My aim is to search for a particular element in the list containing 'a'. On running the code it can be seen that, it only returns the first occurrence of the String that has the element 'a'. list Eg: (aleah, alex, arthur, john, eerie).

**Obtained Output**:aleah.

**Expected Output**:It should have returned aleah, alex and arthur.

I have pasted my code below kindly have a look at it.

```
public ArrayList<String> searchName(String sn){ 
 // String sn is the the search for character value (e.g 'a' or 'aa')   
    ArrayList<String> searches = new ArrayList<>();

     for(String n : names){ 
        // names list is declared in the other method and handles all the name values
        // loop through the list. Am i using the right loop?
        if(n.contains(sn)){
         // if a specific index in the list contains the sn
            searches.add(n);
         // stored in in the new list searches
            displaySearches(searches);
         // called displaySearches and passed the arralist searches.
        }

        else
            System.out.println("No results for " + sn);
            break;
    }


    return searches;




}

public void displaySearches(ArrayList<String> searches){

    for(String s: searches){
        System.out.println(s);
        // populates all the search results from the list.

    }


}
```

Comment: your `else` block shouldn't be in the for loop. The `break` instruction stop the loop

Comment: two problems , calling display after every search match and second `break`  if not  contains (remove break part & display after search complete )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `else` statement is creating the problem here. Just remove it or place it outside the loop.

You can do something like this.

```
public ArrayList<String> searchName(String sn){ 

    ArrayList<String> searches = new ArrayList<>();

    //1. First add all the matches to the `searches` List.
    for(String n : names){ 
        if(n.contains(sn)){
            searches.add(n);
        }
    }

    //2. Now if the `searches` list is NOT empty, it means that 
    //   there were some matches, then display those matches
    if(!searches.isEmpty()) {
        displaySearches(searches);
    } else {
        //3. Otherwise print that there wasn't any match.
        System.out.println("No results for " + sn);
    }

    return searches;
}

public void displaySearches(ArrayList<String> searches){
    for(String s: searches){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already removed the else block and the break statement. I have now retrieved the items from the list with 'a'. However, there were duplicate items being displayed. Sample run (alessa
alessa
alexa
alessa
alexa
andrea
)

Comment: Yes. You were getting duplicates because you were calling `displaySearches()` method from your `for` loop. That's why in my example I've kept it outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
    else
        System.out.println("No results for " + sn);
        break;
```

Setting a `break` statement means that it'll break the full loop, not checking any further items - and it always does this after the first string from the array, because you haven't put any brackets for your `else`.

Removing the `break;` should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

İf you want to find all strings containing 'A's, then, else part should be deleted. Since you don't use parenthesis after else , second n value is not checked because of break statement.

I recommend you to remove else part of your code and check again.  Moreover, display function can be called after loop is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Because your breaking the loop after the else condition

```
public ArrayList<String> searchName(String sn){ 
 // String sn is the the search for character value (e.g 'a' or 'aa')   
    ArrayList<String> searches = new ArrayList<>();

     for(String n : names){ 
        // names list is declared in the other method and handles all the name values
        // loop through the list. Am i using the right loop?
        if(n.contains(sn)){
         // if a specific index in the list contains the sn
            searches.add(n);
         // stored in in the new list searches
            displaySearches(searches);
         // called displaySearches and passed the arralist searches.
        }


    }
    if(searches.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("No results for " + sn);
    }else{
        displaySearches(searches);
    }

    return searches;




}

public void displaySearches(ArrayList<String> searches){

    for(String s: searches){
        System.out.println(s);
        // populates all the search results from the list.

    }


}
```

Comment: Yes thanks, i now get all the items with 'a'. However, I have duplicate items being returned.

Comment: Inputs (ayla
aranda
aleah
roco
eerie)

Comment: Outputs (ayla
ayla
aranda
ayla
aranda
aleah)

Comment: @JongOnin Use a Set instead of a List to get rid of the duplicates